# Can't compile with iOS4 as base sdk

Tags: xcode4, ios4, ios5

First of all please excuse me if the question it's in itself stupid.

I've downloaded a few weeks ago Xcode 4. The problem is that I've discovered that i'm compiling my applications only for iOS5. If I go to the project settings I can see as base sdk iOS5 and it's the only option available.

As far as I know, I can't download one sdk as a separate download.

How Can I support iOS 4.3?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base SDK should be the currently available one - it's the version of the SDK that you have installed to compile against.

However, further down the settings list you'll see that you can set the "Deployment Target" to be for lower versions iOS. That's the one that you'll want to change...

Comment: Thanks tarmes, It was a bit confusing for me :)